# Query XML with nested nodes on Cross Apply

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, cursor, cross-apply

Given a XML structured like this:

```
<ROOT_NODE>
    <FOLDER_LIST>
        <FOLDER>
            <CODE_FOLDER>1</CODE_FOLDER>
            <DESCRIPTION>This is a folder</DESCRIPTION>
            <DATA_LIST>
                <DATA>
                    <CODE_DATA>100</CODE_DATA>
                    <OPTIONS>
                        <OPTION>
                            <CODE_OPTION>200</CODE_OPTION>
                            <PRINT_TEXT>This is a test</PRINT_TEXT>
                        </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>
                            <CODE_OPTION>200</CODE_OPTION>
                            <PRINT_TEXT>This is a test</PRINT_TEXT>
                        </OPTION>
                    </OPTIONS>
                </DATA>
            </DATA_LIST>
        </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER_LIST>
</ROOT_NODE>
```

First I put the values of the first level (FOLDER) inside a temporary table called @tmpFolders using

```
FROM @xml.nodes('ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') as folder(id)
```

Then I declared a cursor on @tmpFolders

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT CODE_FOLDER, DESCRIPTION FROM @tmpFolders 
OPEN cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @codeFolder, @description
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
```

Inside the cursor I insert the values of the second level (DATA) using CROSS APPLY into another temporary table called @tmpData

```
INSERT INTO @tmpData(CODE_DATA)
SELECT data.id.value('CODE_DATA[1]','INT'))
FROM @xml.nodes('ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') as folder(Id)
    CROSS APPLY folder.Id.nodes('DATA_LIST/DATA') as data(Id)
```

Up to this point, everything works correctly.
Now I need the get the values from the third level (OPTION) and insert them into another temporary table called @tmpOptions
I tried adding another CROSS APPLY but without success

```
INSERT INTO @tmpOptions(CODE_OPTION, PRINT_TEXT)
SELECT data.id.value('CODE_DATA[1]','INT')),
       option.id.value('CODE_OPTION[1]','INT'))
       option.id.value('PRINT_TEXT[1]','VARCHAR(50)'))
FROM @xml.nodes('ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') as folder(Id)
    CROSS APPLY folder.Id.nodes('DATA_LIST/DATA') as data(Id)
    CROSS APPLY data.Id.nodes('OPTIONS/OPTION') as option(Id)
```

I don't get any errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is not correct...

> I don't get any errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

There are some closing brackets to much, a comma is missing and you are using reserved words, which should be qouted like `[option]`. This must throw errors...

Try it like this

```
SELECT [data].id.value('CODE_DATA[1]','INT'),
       [option].id.value('CODE_OPTION[1]','INT'),
       [option].id.value('PRINT_TEXT[1]','VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @xml.nodes('ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') as folder(Id)
    CROSS APPLY folder.Id.nodes('DATA_LIST/DATA') as [data](Id)
    CROSS APPLY [data].Id.nodes('OPTIONS/OPTION') as [option](Id)
```

### BUT ...

Your code is - probably! - not doing what you'd expect if there is more than one `<FOLDER>` or more than one `<DATA>`. Within your `CURSOR` you read all elements without any filter to the given parent...

Anyway, this is not the way you should do that. Avoid `CURSOR` wherever you can!

What is your final goal? If you want to transfer this structure in related tables. Is it on purpose, that the option's code is the same (`200`) for both? Might be a copy'n'paste error... If all internal codes were unique it was as easy as:

```
SELECT Fld.value(N'(CODE_FOLDER/text())[1]',N'int') AS Folder_Code
      ,Fld.value(N'(DESCRIPTION/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Folder_Description
      ,Dt.value(N'(CODE_DATA/text())[1]',N'int') AS Data_Code
      ,Opt.value(N'(CODE_OPTION/text())[1]',N'int') AS Option_Code
      ,Opt.value(N'(PRINT_TEXT/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Option_Text
      --Generate running IDs, you might add an existing max id if you have to insert into filled tables
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Fld.value(N'(CODE_FOLDER/text())[1]',N'int')) AS FolderId
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Fld.value(N'(CODE_FOLDER/text())[1]',N'int')
                                 ,Dt.value(N'(CODE_DATA/text())[1]',N'int')) AS DataId
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Fld.value(N'(CODE_FOLDER/text())[1]',N'int')
                                 ,Dt.value(N'(CODE_DATA/text())[1]',N'int')
                                 ,Opt.value(N'(CODE_OPTION/text())[1]',N'int')) AS OptionId
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') AS A(Fld)
OUTER APPLY Fld.nodes(N'DATA_LIST/DATA') AS B(Dt)
OUTER APPLY Dt.nodes(N'OPTIONS/OPTION') AS C(Opt);
```

If the internal codes are not unique, you can go this way:

```
WITH Folders AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FolderId
           ,Fld.value(N'(CODE_FOLDER/text())[1]',N'int') AS Folder_Code
           ,Fld.value(N'(DESCRIPTION/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Folder_Description
           ,Fld.query(N'DATA_LIST/DATA') AS Node_data
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ROOT_NODE/FOLDER_LIST/FOLDER') AS A(Fld)
)
,FoldersWithDatas AS
(
    SELECT Folders.FolderId
          ,Folders.Folder_Code
          ,Folders.Folder_Description
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS DataId
          ,Dt.value(N'(CODE_DATA/text())[1]',N'int') AS Data_Code
          ,Dt.query(N'OPTIONS/OPTION') AS Node_data
    FROM Folders
    OUTER APPLY Folders.Node_data.nodes(N'DATA') AS A(Dt)
)
SELECT   FoldersWithDatas.FolderId
        ,FoldersWithDatas.Folder_Code
        ,FoldersWithDatas.Folder_Description
        ,FoldersWithDatas.DataId
        ,FoldersWithDatas.Data_Code
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS OptionId
        ,Dt.value(N'(CODE_OPTION/text())[1]',N'int') AS Option_Code
FROM FoldersWithDatas
OUTER APPLY FoldersWithDatas.Node_data.nodes(N'OPTION') AS A(Dt);
```

This would work with any number of folder, nested Datas and nested options...

Write this into a temp table and use `SELECT DISTINCT` to insert each set of data together with the appropriate foreign key into its table.

Comment: The syntax error are not present in my original xml file (what I posted is just a simplified version that I wrote on the spot).
I later found out that the what I wrote actually works, I made a copy/paste mistake in the where clause.
Anyway I'm quite interested in what you suggested. I will let you know as soon as I try it.

Comment: I have just tested and it works like a charm. A lot easier and faster than the method I was using. Thank you!